# The Android "back" button

Tags: java, android, back-button

I am an Apple iPhone user.  I have never owned an Android of any type so I am used to the button I have to tap on the screen to go back a screen instead of the physical "back button" that Android has.  An iPhone developer has to code the back button in for the user to operate the game but an Android developer does not necessarily have to code a back button and can just rely on the physical button on the phone.

My question is if it is okay for me not to code a button for my Android app and just let the user use the hardware back button on their phone?  If there is no back button to tap, will an Android user instinctively know to hit the physical back button to jump back a screen?  I don't really know this answer since I have never owned an Android and always rely on the iPhone coded in buttons.

The picture below is me coding in the back button instead of relying on the physical button on the phone.  I am wanting to back out the back button from my code.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to do anything, unless you have good reason.  Indeed, you should *not* do anything.  The back button is totally instinctive and natural.  With intent flags, you can control how activities navigate between themselves anyway.

Comment: Yes, the user will "know" to use the standard back button.  And no, adding your own back button (with the same semantics) is both unnecessary and potentially confusing.  Don't do it :)  Here's a good discussion of the "semantics" of the standard Android back-button: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Thanks to you two and everyone else that came up with the same answer!  I don't have Android instincts yet so I did not know the answer was so obvious.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shouldn't code a back button on your app. See the pure android [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html) here for more info on android apps look and feel.

Comment: I don't have Android instincts yet so I did not know the answer was so obvious.  :)

Answer (score 3):

Every Android Device contains Back Button. And Android users using the Back button since first version of android released. They All have idea on Back button , No need to implement it separately, User already Habituated it.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed for both iOS and Android, and find the best answer to be using both. Android users know to use the hardware back button, but new users, or former iPhone users, often expect an on-screen button. There is no harm in having both, and an on-screen button may be a nice visual touch.

Cases where you may decide not to have a back button include layout for smaller screens - when screen real-estate is very precious. Just keep in mind that the most important part of an application is the user experience.

The key is to make your app as user friendly to all users - but don't take away the expected experience from dedicated Android users (for instance, if you are developing a single-activity app with multiple popup `View`s, the ideal performance of the back button will close the view, rather than closing the whole app).

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to have a button to go back at the top right of the activity, there is a way to add one on the action bar. Take a look at the [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) page if you want.